# Why is the method File.delete() not working?

Tags: java, file, netbeans

I have been frustrated for almost 2 days trying to find the flaw because the `registry.delete()` method **does not delete** the file "Registry.txt". I'm working with a GUI, and every time I click on a row of a `JTable` and then click on the "Ban" button, it does not delete the file "Registry.txt", and it does not write either! However, if I do it from another class, like the class that has the `main()` method, it clears properly. What I *wanted* to do is **delete a line from the Registry.txt, writing in another .txt file all of the lines that did not contain a certain `String` name, and then rename it to the name Registry.txt**. I do not know what is happening. Below is my code:

```
ActionListener ban = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int fila = table.getSelectedRow();
        String nombre = (String) modelo.getValueAt(fila, 0);
        modelo.removeRow(fila);
        try {
            removeUser(nombre);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
};
btnBanear.addActionListener(ban);

...

public void removeUser(String nombre) throws IOException {
    String lee = null;
    String usuario = "";
    CharSequence aux = nombre;
    try {
        registro = new File("Registro.txt");
        tempFile = new File("Registro1.txt");
        lector = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(registro));
        fw = new FileWriter(tempFile);
        writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    while ((lee = lector.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(aux);
        if (lee.contains(nombre)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            writer.write(lee);
        }
    }
    lector.close();
    fw.close();
    writer.close();
    registro.delete();
}
```

Comment: *"and every time I click on a row of a JTable and then click on the "Ban" button"* - I'd be interested in seeing a runnable example which demonstrates that work flow - because it's likely the (start) of the problem

Comment: I'd also suggest that you take a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) as you're creating a possible scenario where the file resources are left unclosed

Comment: Is it creating/updating Registro1.txt correctly? I'm wondering if the action listener's thread has a different CWD than you're expecting.

Comment: Please indent your code next time. This one was on the house :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we have quite enough data to see exactly why this is happening, but I can give you some strong suspicions.

`File.delete()` throws four possible exceptions; three of which apply here. `NoSuchFileException` (worth specifically checking for), `IOException`, and `SecurityException`. `NoSuchFileException` is derived from `IOException` and would be caught anyway; though you might want to catch for it still as casting it to an `IOException` is going to remove relevant data. `SecurityException` is generally when a security manager gets in the way, which happens all the time on web-based programs. I'm wondering if your file is some kind of an applet or its modern equivalent, the web application? `SecurityException` is a `RuntimeException`, so you don't have to catch for it, but you can and probably should. That would explain worlds.

Lastly, you can also use `File.deleteIfExists()`. This returns a value of true if the file was actually present to be deleted, and false if it could not be found. Worth looking into, because if your path is getting skewed and the file can't be found at the provided location, then it won't be deleted. It's reasonable to think that your program might have a different working directory than you're thinking it does. This is more or less the same as checking for `NoSuchFileException`, though.

You might even check your working directory, to be sure, with `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))`.

---

My money is on `SecurityException` or the path being wrong. However, if I'm wrong about this, it would be nice if you could show us your other button code, because there could be a relevant problem there, too.